# How to pass prop as undefined by leaving it out in a declaration in react/typescript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wan't to do this

[image: Label missing error]

But i get an typescript error saying that label is missing. So when i explicitly say that it should be undefined the error disappears like in the image below

[image: No errors]

My interface looks like this

```
export default interface Props {
  onPress: () => void
  label: string | null
}
```

I want to be able to leave it out and thereby passing undefined. Do some Compiler options exist for this? Or a workaround in the interface? Or some other way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the field optional using `?`:

```
export default interface Props {
  onPress: () => void
  label?: string
}
```